# Kann das Wort "implementieren" auch für physische Objekte benutzt werden?

Tags: verb-usage

Das Wort *implementieren* wird in der Regel im Zusammenhang mit Prozessen oder logischen Strukturen wie z.B. in Software oder Hardware benutzt.
Die Definition und Herkunft [entsprechend dem Duden](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/implementieren) nennt Programme, Software und Hardware explizit als Beispiele.

Allerdings kam die Frage auf, ob das Wort auch für physische Objekte benutzt werden kann.
Die "Implementierung eines Prozessors" beschreibt üblicherweise entweder die abstrakte Logik, die durch das physische Objekt abgebildet wird ("der Prozessor implementiert diese Instruktion nicht") oder aber den Herstellungsprozess ("Es wird Silizium verarbeitet, um den Prozessor zu implementieren").
Die Definition des Dudens würde, wenn die geklammerten Beispiele 1:1 übernommen werden würden aber auch die Installation eines Prozessors auf einem Mainboard im Zuge des Zusammenbaus eines Computersystems als "den Prozessor implementieren" erlauben:

> (Software, Hardware o. Ä.) in ein bestehendes Computersystem einsetzen, einbauen und so ein funktionsfähiges Programm (4) erstellen

Für mich wirkt diese Wortwahl sehr unintuitiv, und auch die Herkunft laut Duden wirkt nicht, als ob der Sprachgebrauch dahingehend richtig wäre:

> zu englisch to implement, eigentlich = aus-, durchführen, zu: implement = Werkzeug, Gerät, im Sinne von „das, was dazu dient, etwas mit etwas anzufüllen“ < spätlateinisch implementum, eigentlich = das Angefülltsein, zu lateinisch implere = anfüllen; erfüllen

Welches sich für mich so liest als würde es sich auf die Nutzung eines Werkzeugs, nicht aber auf das Werkzeug selbst beziehen.
Folglich könnte man, nach meinem Verständnis, den Einbau des Prozessors implementieren, nicht aber den Prozessor selbst zu implementieren als selbigen Akt sehen.

Kann das Wort *implementieren* auch für physische Objekte benutzt werden?

Comment: Ich bezweifel den Abschnitt über den Herstellungsprozess. "Es wird Silizium verarbeitet um den Prozessor zu implementieren" ergbit m.E. auch keinen Sinn. "Es wird Wärmeleitpaste verwendet, um den Prozessor zu implementieren." oder meinetwegen "Sislzium wird in den Prozessor implementiert" (wobei mir auch da sich die Fussnägel hochrollen) schon eher, aber dann sind wir wieder im Einbaubereich und warum der bezweifelt wird kann ich leider nicht nachvollziehen ^^.

Comment: Hardware ist eine Bezeichnung für physische Objekte.

Comment: Ich meine auch daß im wesentlichen Software, ein Verfahren, ein Vorgehen, ein "Workflow" implementiert wird und weniger die Dinge, die beim runterfallen ein Geräusch machen. Aber im Zuge einer Implementation eines möglicherweise komplexen Verfahrens kann natürlich auch was Hartes verbaut werden. Aber das wäre dann meiner Meinung nach nicht eine Implementation an sich, nur ein Vorgang im Zuge der Implentation ...

Comment: Implementieren bedeutet für mich eigentlich die konkrete Ausführung eines theoretischen Konstrukts bzw. einer allgemeinen Idee. Insofern kann für mich auch ein bestimmter Typ von Kaffemaschine eine Implementierung der allgemeinen Idee des  Kaffeeautomaten darstellen oder auch eine konkrete Kaffemaschine die Implementierung dieses Typs. Wenn ich das richtig sehe, betrachtet der Duden "implementieren" aber auch als Synonym von "installieren".

Answer (score 1):

*To implement sth.* hat eine Vielzahl möglicher Bedeutungen.

Das Phänomen tritt oft auf, dass ein fremdsprachiger Begriff wie hier *to implement* nur in einem Kontext intensiv in die andere Sprache transferiert wird. Dort wird er häufig nicht nachgeschlagen, sondern aus dem Kontext wird auf die Bedeutung zurückgeschlossen, und so eine verengte Wortbedeutung angenommen.

Die dt. Sprache ist jedoch sehr plastisch und erlaubt jedermann zu jeder Zeit Wörter fremder Herkunft zu importieren; niemand fragt nach einer Erlaubnis, keine Instanz könnte sie erteilen und ebensowenig verwehren. Wenn jmd. den Begriff nachgeschlagen hat, und so um seine Bedeutungsbreite weiß, kann er also sehr gut den Begriff auch da bzw. so verwenden, wie es Dir oder anderen bislang nicht begegnet ist.

Das Onlinewörterbuch dict.leo.org [listet](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/implement), neben anderen:

- umsetzen
- bestücken
- ausführen
- durchführen
- realisieren (*verwirklichen*, nicht *bemerken*, as I realized)
- ausführen
- anwenden
- durchsetzen

Man kann also einen Prozessor, eine Bohr- oder Küchenmaschine implementieren, nicht nur Sortier- und Suchalgorithmen.